# .htaccess dynamic URL with two strings

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to create dynamic URL with 2 strings

```
string 1 = america
string 2 = mcdonals-burgers-so-celicious
```

My `.htaccess` code is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+).html$ state.php?state=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I want to make `america-mcdonals-burgers-so-delicious.html`.

but this URL 2 string `$_GET` results is

```
    echo $_GET['state'];
    echo $_GET['category'];

america-mcdonals-burgers-sodelicious
```

I am sure I make mistake with regex codes... But still i didn't find my answer...

Comment: Is "state" (string 1) always just 1 word?

Comment: sometimes it can be 2 words...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+).html$
> ```

This regex is somewhat ambiguous. You are using a hyphen as the delimiter between your 2 parameters, but also allowing each parameter to contain hyphens as well. Where you are expecting the delimiter to be (after the first word) is not how the regex matches since the `+` regex quantifier is *greedy* by default and consumes as much as possible.

So, the first capturing group matches `america-mcdonals-burgers-so` and the second matches `delicious`, not `america` and `mcdonals-burgers-so-delicious` as you are expecting.

#### If "state" (first parameter) only consists of one word

The only way you can resolve this (and keep the hyphen as the parameter delimiter) is if the "state" (string 1) parameter only ever consists of one word and so you can remove the hyphen from the first capturing group.

For example:

```
^([a-zA-Z_]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.html$
```

(And remember to backslash-escape the literal dot before `html`.)

#### If "state" (first parameter) can consists of multiple words (ie. multiple hyphens)

However, if the "state" can consist of multiple words (and consequently multiple *hyphens*) then you need to use a different character as the parameter delimiter. eg. `/america-two/mcdonals-burgers-so-delicious.html` and therefore use a regex like `^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.html$` instead. Importantly, the parameter *delimiter* (`/` in this case) should be unique.

Comment: Thank you, with 1 word, working without error...

Comment: @Edursun You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" to help other readers (and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Thanks, much appreciated. :)